# update a DialogFragment view (and using a AsyncTask)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment, dialogfragment

I'm updating my app by replacing all the deprecated methods. Now, I'm having problem with the DialogFragments.

I have a DialogActivity like this:

```
public class Actualizar extends FragmentActivity 
{
    /**BASIC ACTIVITY CODE HERE **/

    /**WHERE THAT I NEED HELP **/
    OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            AsyncTaskActualizarDatos task = new AsyncTaskActualizarDatos();
            task.execute();
        }
    };
}
```

When I click on a button I want execute am AsyncTask. This task should show a DialogFragment with a custom layout and download via FTP some file.

The AsyncTask is like this:

```
public class AsyncTaskActualizarDatos extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    FragmentoComunicacion fragmento;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        fragmento = FragmentoComunicacion.actualizarDatos();
        fragmento.show(fm, "dialog");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) 
    {
          /** DO SOMETHING HERE **/
    }
}
```

And the fragment is like this:

```
public class FragmentoComunicacion extends DialogFragment
{
    public static FragmentoComunicacion actualizarDatos()
    {
        FragmentoComunicacion f = new FragmentoComunicacion();
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_actualizar_datos, container);
        getDialog().setTitle("Title");
        return v;
    }
}
```

Now... I'm trying to update the views in the fragment (using publishProgress), **but I don't know where I can do this.** When I try to use fragmento.findView() in [doInBackground()] I got a nullPointerException.

I'm confused... What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the call you are looking for is:

fragmento.getDialog().findViewById(...)

Comment: Yeah you are rigth... My problem was that was calling a View in the doInBackground method...

Comment: Ah, yes, that too is a problem. Did you figure out how to do in onPostExecute?

Comment: Yep... after 8 hours of good sleep I could see the all things I was doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

```
FragmentoComunicacion fragmento;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() 
{
    FragmentoComunicacion fragmento = FragmentoComunicacion.actualizarDatos();
    fragmento.show(fm, "dialog");
    super.onPreExecute();
}
```

you're hiding your the parent field fragmento with local field fragmento, you need to change this:`FragmentoComunicacion fragmento = FragmentoComunicacion.actualizarDatos();`
to this:`fragmento = FragmentoComunicacion.actualizarDatos();`

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but that was just a typo... Now the code is correct.. (well, not really correct... you know)